# PHP - Consulta SQL

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando implementar um código para listar informações de 3 tabelas. Eu quero que exiba na tela somente os dados que foram cadastrado pelo usuário `id = '20'`. Esse valor '20' estou pegando de uma variável de sessão e quero colocar na minha função de listar produto porém não estou conseguindo.

segue:

```
$idSessao = $_SESSION['sessaoId'];

function listaProdutos($conexao){
    $produtos = array();
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, "select p.*, c.nome as categoria_nome, u.id as id_usuario from produtos as p inner join categorias as c on c.id = p.categoria_id inner join usuarios as u on u.id = p.usuario_id where p.usuario_id = 20");
    while ($produto = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
        array_push($produtos, $produto);
    }
    return $produtos;
}
```

Onde está `p.usuario_id = 20` gostaria de fazer isso `p.usuario_id = {$idSessao}` porém ele não retorna nada.

Comment: Já verificou se você esta conseguindo recuperar o valor da sessão corretamente?  Já tentou imprimir o código SQL para ver se ele está correto? Normalmente fazendo testes desse tipo se chega a raiz do problema.

Comment: É o valor da variável não estava entrando dentro da função, por isso ficava em branco. Mas o amigo Rodrigo Sartori mostrou alternativas para pegar o valor e coloca-la dentro da função

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se código tem um problema de escopo de variável, $idSessao não é uma variável global, portanto a função não "vê" essa variável. Sobre escopo de funções dê uma olhada [aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.scope.php)

Para resolver o problema, ou você declara $idSessao dentro da função(não recomendo).

```
global $idSessao
```

Ou você coloca esta linha dentro da função :

```
$idSessao = $_SESSION['sessaoId'];
```

ou ainda coloque um parâmetro na função dessa forma

```
$idSessao = $_SESSION['sessaoId'];

function listaProdutos($conexao,$usuario_id){
    $produtos = array();
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, "select p.*, c.nome as categoria_nome, u.id as id_usuario from produtos as p inner join categorias as c on c.id = p.categoria_id inner join usuarios as u on u.id = p.usuario_id where p.usuario_id =".$usuario_id); // Corrigi o seu código aqui
    $produtos = mysqli_fetch_all($resultado); //não precisa de laço while se vai retornar um array 
    return $produtos;
}

//chamada da função
function listaProdutos($conexao,$idSessao);
```

Essa terceira opção vai lhe proporcionar uma flexibilidade maior na função, já que o id_usuario poderá vir de qualquer lugar, tornando a função mais reaproveitável.
Sobre o mysqli_fetch_all você pode ler mais [aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)

Comment: Quero agradecer a Rodrigo Sartori. Eu utilizei a 3 alternativa e funcionou perfeitamente.  Obrigado!